# I need to use a series of variables in a function that is called several times, I want to do that in the fastest possible way

Tags: matlab

I have to define a series of variables at the beginning of a function. Since I am using the function several times (10,000), I'd like to do that in the fastest possible way. At the moment I just created a series of global variables in the main script and I call them at the beginning of my function as it follows:

```
global x
global y
global z
```

However, I have noticed that it still quite time consuming (compared with the rest of the code of the function). Since I am not an expert MATLAB programmer, I'd like to know if there is any "more optimal" approach to do that.
Thank you.

```
function [Mosk,D]= Moskovitz(x,t,INTC)

global v
global densc
global densm
global w
global IC
global LBC
global RBC
global nic
global nlbc
global nrbc
global alpha1
global alpha2
global alpha3
global dx
global dt

i=round(t/dt);
j=round(x/dx);

D=0;
N=-10^36;

        for k=1:nic
            if IC(3,k)<=densc
                if (IC(2,k)+v*t >=x) & (IC(1,k)-w*t<=x)
                    if (IC(1,k)+v*t <=x)
                        u=-v;
                        t1=0;
                        x1=x-v*t;
                         dens=IC(3,k);

                    else
                        u=(IC(1,k)-x)/t;
                        t1=0;
                        x1=IC(1,k);
                         dens=densc;

                    end
                end
            else
                if (IC(2,k)+v*t >=x) & (IC(1,k)-w*t<=x)
                    if (IC(2,k)-w*t >=x)
                        u=w;
                        t1=0;
                        x1=x+w*t;
                         dens=IC(3,k);

                    else
                        u=(IC(2,k)-x)/t;
                        t1=0;
                        x1=IC(2,k);
                         dens=densc;

                    end
                end
            end

           if (IC(2,k)+v*t >=x) & (IC(1,k)-w*t<=x) 
           tmp=-(t-t1)*densc*(u+v)+alpha1(k,1)+(x1-IC(1,k))*IC(3,k); 
           if tmp>=N 
               N=tmp;
               D=dens;

           end 
           end
        end 
end
```

Comment: `global` are generally a bad idea. If possible, pass the variables directly to your function as arguments. In order to do more: please post a [mcve], detailing your code. This way we can see what you're doing

Comment: Might I suggest posting your function that you'd like to optimize? :)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind if you are using the MATLAB profiler is that sometimes the function overhead gets "billed" to the first line of the function, and it doesn't literally mean that the global declarations are eating all your run time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am posting below a short version of the function I need to optimize. I placed some tic-toc and I noticed that in order to run the first 20 lines where I am calling the variables, it takes about one or two orders of magnitude longer than the rest...Consider that I need to call this function several thousands times, so even a small gain would help me a lot

Comment: @Michele I think the usage of `global` variables takes a lot of time. As I said before: try and change your code so everything is called as an input parameter in the code, i.e. put everything in a structure or cell array and call that as input in your function.

Comment: Consider placing all of your variables as fields in a structure and passing the structure into your function.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. So for instance, you'd create an array/matrix with the values I am using in the function and just provide it as input in the function, e.g. function(matrix)?

Comment: I thought that also "opening" a structure would take time, that's why I tried with global variables

Comment: *Adriaan, and yes. Though unless all your variables have the same size and class (i.e. they are all scalars of double class), you need a cell or structure.

Comment: Thanks Adriaan. Yes, they are all single scalars or matrices. So, just to be sure, would you suggest me to create a single cell/structure for all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Declaring variables is not necessary in MATLAB, but it is still good programming practice.  All you have to do is initialize them:

```
x = 0;
y = 0;
z = 0;
```

Regardless of what the profiler says, this takes essentially no time.

If you would like the values to carry over from one iteration to the next, you can use the **persistent** keyword.

Comment: How's declaring variables "not necessary"?

Comment: Are you sure about that? this variables come from the main script so if I don't declare them, I get an error...

Comment: Do you think you could give me a simple example of persistent keyword. I am not very familiar. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "declaring variables is not necessary"?

Comment: declaring a variable before you use it is not necessary.  In essence, the first time you assign to a variable in matlab, it declares it for you.  There isn't an equivalent to "int x;" in C/C++/Java.

Comment: You declare persistent variables just like global variables, right at the top of the function.  If you say "persistent x", the first time you call the function, you create the variable x, and it is an empty matrix.  If you assign a value to x in the first function call, that value will persist into the next call of that same function.  If you walk through the second function call in the debugger, right after you execute "persistent x" at the top, you can evaluate x and see that it has the same value from the previous call to that function.